# Error when login in on deezer developer portal

Tags: deezer

when I try to get access to deezer developer portal, I'm redirect to a blank page with this text

You have to login to accept the terms and conditions of the simple API.

And a button to login.
Which when pressed come back to this page.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: The login button should open a popup allowing you to sign in, do you have a popup blocker?

Comment: @Fred_Dzr Thanks for the reply, i'm trying to access from my chrome on android device. Without blockers